# Using NSDate as a property gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am adding NSDate as a pointer with a property, and every time I unload my view, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I am doing (not posting full code):

### .h

```
NSDate *scheduledDate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *scheduledDate;
```

### .m

```
@synthesize scheduledDate;

    - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [asset release];
    [passedDate release];
    [eventDate release];
    [eventName release];
}
```

I have not done anything else with the pointer, but I still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Why is this happening?  Is there a different way to set the property for NSDate?

**SORRY:**

I fixed an error in my question code, it was only a copy and paste issue, not a fix to my problem, it still exists.

Comment: Your code is way too incomplete/ill-formed...

Comment: Perhaps a type but you're @property is the NSString *passedDate and your @synthesizing the NSData *scheduledData,

Comment: If you don't know why it's crashing, what makes you think you're qualified to know what code isn't relevant to your problem? Please post more code.

Comment: You say you're using an NSDate as a property, but do not show any NSDate properties.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy and paste mistake, see my update

Comment: Your update still hasn't provided the necessary code to even begin to help. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [super dealloc] before the release in your dealloc implementation.  That means the [scheduledDate release] is release some non-free memory (which is no longer nil).

Specifically, change the order so [super dealloc] is last:

```
- (void)dealloc {        
    [asset release];
    [passedDate release];
    [eventDate release];
    [eventName release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, for noticing something that I would not have even realized!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks inconsistent.  The @property declaration should be for "NSDate *scheduledDate", not "NSString* ...".

Comment: The property isn't for `scheduledDate`, it's for `passedDate`. Also, this won't cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Then how would the "@synthesize scheduledDate" even compile?

Comment: Ah, thanks.  We still may need to see more code.  Where is [release] called?  If in -(void)dealloc, it has to happen before super dealloc e.g. [scheduledDate release]; [super dealloc], not after.

Comment: @Peter - You nailed it!  I had [super dealloc] first, and that is what was crashing it.  Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I thought Xcode warned about having `[super dealloc]` first in a subclass's dealloc?

Comment: @Nic OK, posted a new answer, didn't know I could have two.
@vicvicvic It doesn't appear to post a warning, perhaps there is a flag to turn that on.  You are correct: any warnings from the Objective-C compiler are usually real problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *scheduledDate;` then there is no need to synthesize `scheduledDate`.

Also, how are you determining the value of `scheduledDate`? *post the code you are using for it*.

Also, post the crash log that your app produces.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@property (nonatomic, retain)` is for "passedDate", not "scheduledDate".  Since "scheduledDate" is not getting instantiated and retained by `@property (nonatomic, retain)`, then attempting to release it is attempting to release something that hasn't been created yet (it isn't being synthesized as a property).